# output all the elements of an array - C

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to output all the elements of an arrary which contains input from the user.
Like for example if the user inputs smile, happy and sad for the adjectives, i want to output that back to the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int counter_1, counter_2, counter_3, tracker;

    printf("Enter a number of adjectives: ");
    int numAdj;

    scanf("%d", &numAdj);

    printf("Enter a number of nouns: ");
    int numNouns;

    scanf("%d", &numNouns);

    char adj[numAdj];
    char nouns[numNouns];

    printf("Please enter %d adjectives: \n", numAdj);

    for (counter_1 = 0; counter_1 <= numAdj - 1; counter_1++) {
        scanf("%s", &adj[counter_1]);
    }

    printf("Please enter %d nouns: \n", numNouns);

    for (counter_2 = 0; counter_2 <= numNouns - 1; counter_2++) {
        scanf("%s", &nouns[counter_2]);
    }

    for (counter_3 = 0; counter_3 <= numAdj - 1; counter_3++) {
        printf("%s", &adj[counter_3]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out why I can't output the data of the array.

Comment: What happens instead? Does it compile? Do you see a run time error, is it printing empty strings?

Comment: it only ouputs the first letter of each element of the array :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing from the array `adj`, which only has room for `numAdj` elements, i.e., if `numAdj` is 3 you can only access elements `adj[0]`, `adj[1]`, and `adj[2]`. However, the final loop iterates to `numAdj * numNouns`, which goes past the end of `adj` whenever `numNouns` is not 0 (in which case it only prints the first element, `adj[0]`).

Use the `for` line from each of your two previous loops to properly iterate over `adj` and `nouns`.

Additionally both `adj` and `nouns` are arrays of individual `char` elements, i.e., single characters, not strings. You need to make them arrays of arrays of chars (as C strings are arrays of chars, an array of C strings is an array of arrays of chars).

Comment: i did that, however, I'm still only getting the output of the first letter of the element...How do I output the entire word that `adj[0]` holds?

Comment: @Sentrl `char adj[numAdj][20];` and then `scanf("%19s", adj[counter_1]);` in the loop. Similar for the nouns.

Comment: @Sentrl: `adj[0]` cannot hold an entire word, only a single character (letter) - since `adj` is an array of `char`, each element is a single `char`. You need to make the elements of `adj` arrays of char, i.e., add another dimension to the array, e.g., as shown by Daniel Fischer above.

Answer (score 0):

you have written:

```
char adj[numAdj];
char nouns[numNouns];
```

next you are doing:

```
...
scanf("%s", &adj[counter_1]);
...
```

but `&adj[counter_1]` is reference to `char`, but scanf waiting for reference to `char *`. It is wrong. The same problem exists with `char nouns[numNouns];` array, it's an array of chars, not an array of strings.

Comment: So all in all, You are saying I should have it as `char * adj[numAdj]`?

Comment: @Sentrl Then you'd still need to allocate memory to each `adj[i]`.

Comment: for example you can do `char adj[numAdj][MAXWORD];
    char nouns[numNouns][MAXWORD];`

Comment: @Sentrl `char *adj[numAdj]` would be an array with room for `numAdj` pointers to char (`char *`). This could indeed be used, but only if you set those pointers to point to valid memory locations big enough to hold your strings. You could do this on the fly by first reading each word into a big buffer and then copying each word to a newly allocated location, but in this simple case it's much easier to just have a 2-dimensional array with fixed space for each word as shown above (where `MAXWORD` is the maximum length of an individual word minus 1).